# How to add and read custom elements or parameters in Log4Net?

Tags: c#, logging, log4net

I have written a Log4net wrapper with custom appenders. I would like to be able to add a custom element or parameter ("MyCustomElement") at the root level of the config and load that up in code when I am initializing my logger.

Please note that I want the parameter/element to be read/loaded by log4net and not by reading the config file manually, this means that whenever the config file is changed, Log4net reloads all the config elements (`log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch("MyLog.config");`)

Ideally I would like the root element to look like this but I am open to any suggestions.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<log4net>
  <root>
    <level value="ALL">
    <MyCustomElement value="true"/>
    <appender-ref ref="CustomFileAppender"/>
  </root>

  <appender ....>
  .....

</log4net>
```

Please also note that I need the element at the root level and not the Appender level.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're going to have to hack [the source code](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/source-repository.html) to get log4net to do that

Comment: Or write your own config file reading utilities and manually configure Log4Net in code.

Comment: @Eric, I think that's actually a good idea and much simpler to implement. Tnx

Comment: Thanks, here is a link that helped when I had to do that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx